# Why is there no electric field outside a spherical, conducting, non-grounded shell with a dipole in the center?

Tags: electromagnetism

If you place a dipole at the center of a conducting, non-grounded, spherical shell, the electric field outside the shell is zero. However, if there is a point charge in the center, there is an electric field outside.

I understand that the net charge in the system is zero, because of the dipole, and then maybe it's a violation of Gauss's law to have an electric field outside the shell. However, why does dipole by itself (which has an electric field) not violate Gauss's law?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is my source for this question. It's from the book *Conquering the Physics GRE* by Yoni Kahn and Adam Anderson.

[image: question]
[image: answer]

Comment: It would not violate Gauss’ Law to have a field outside, as long as its flux is zero.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Then is there no field outside because the charge in the shell rearranges to cancel the field created by the dipole? Then how would that be different than a point charge in the same spherical shell?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I am not convinced that the field outside would be zero. Which source says that it is?

Comment: I updated my post to include images of where I got this from.

Comment: Hmm. It seems clear to me that positive and negative charges netting to zero will have to arrange themselves on the inside of the conducting shell in order to make the field inside the conducting material be zero. It is not at all obvious to me why positive and negative charge netting to zero could not also form on the outside of the shell. The only reason that comes to mind is “what would cause that to happen?” I can’t think of anything, so I guess it doesn’t happen. But I don’t find this very satisfying.

Comment: If the charges did that on the outside of the shell, they would still cancel the field inside the shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exterior surface of the shell is an equipotential $V_0$. *Assuming* that the potential outside the sphere approaches a finite, constant value $A$ as $r \to \infty$, then a solution to Laplace's equation satisfying these boundary conditions is $V(r) = A + (V_0-A)R/r$.  By the uniqueness of the solutions of Laplace's equation, this is the only possible solution for the exterior region given these boundary conditions.  Thus, the exterior potential must be spherically symmetric, and so must the exterior electric field $\vec{E} = (B/r^2) \hat{r}$.  Invoking Gauss's Law and noting that there is no net charge for any surface enclosing the sphere, we can conclude that $B = 0$, and so $\vec{E} = 0$.

It is, of course, possible to consider situations where the potential does not approach a constant value at infinity;  a standard example of this is the problem of a conducting sphere in an external uniform electric field.  But if we demand that the exterior potential approaches a constant as $r \to \infty$, and there is no net charge inside the sphere, then the exterior potential must be constant and the exterior electric field must be zero.

Finally, I suspect that this argument can be adapted to a non-spherical shell as well.  But the precise details elude me at the moment...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Forgive me, but why can we assume the potential outside the sphere is spherically symmetric? The electric field due to a dipole alone is not spherically symmetric.

Comment: @AsherLantz:  Upon further consideration, we don't actually need to assume that the exterior potential is spherically symmetric.  All we need is that the potential approaches a constant asymptotically;  the spherical symmetry then follows from the uniqueness of solutions to Laplace's equation.  See my edit.

Comment: That clears it up, thank you. One follow up, would it be accurate to say that the spherical shell "converts" the electric field of the dipole to being spherically symmetric. Another way to say this could be that the charges on the outside of the shell align themselves to "fill in the holes" of the electric field of the dipole such that it becomes spherically symmetric (and thus has to be zero). Could be totally off here.