# Field of dipole inside a conducting sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, dipole

I saw [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/electric-field-of-a-spherical-conductor-with-a-dipole-in-the-center.977997/) question about placing a dipole in a conducting shell, what should the $E$ field be? [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572871/why-is-there-no-electric-field-outside-a-spherical-conducting-non-grounded-she) post clears my questions about the outside field- the conductor's electrons will rearrange themselves to cancel out the dipole's $E$ field.

My question is, what is the field *inside* the sphere? The dipole's potential $V = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{p \cdot \hat{r}}{r^2}$ on the sphere's surface is not necessarily equal, so it does not match the equipotential boundary condition as a valid potential field should do.

Comment: Where is the dipole located within the sphere? What is its orientation?

Comment: @BrianBi A perfect dipole at the center of the sphere $p$ facing one direction

Comment: You should try re-posting the question with that detail included, and a description of how you've tried to solve it and what you're stuck on.